# How do I install a distance power switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, interior

I have a pair of Rokit 5 G3 powered monitor speakers. I want to mount a power switch to a control panel on my desk so I can power them on easily. There's ~12 ft of distance between the speakers and the panel on which I'd like the rocker.

My first thought was to use a power strip. However, all the power strips I find have their reset breaker in an awkward position. I want to mount the switch which turns the speakers on so that the switch is facing outward from the panel on my desk. However, power strips tend to have their reset breakers co-planar with the plugs on them, so I can't hide the power cables behind the panel.

This seems like something I could build myself with the right materials. I have some electronics / soldering experience (Arduino projects), but I'm wary to build something that connects directly to main power myself, since I'm not an electrician.

Is there an off-the-shelf product that lets me do this? Barring that, what should I be careful for if I wanted to try building it myself. For reference, there are 2 speaker monitors, and each has a max power draw of 100W @ 120VAC.

---

[image: Diagram of desk size and speaker placement] 
(not to scale)

Comment: How would you feel about having junction boxes and conduit screwed to your desk?  If you're okay with that, you could do it with a standard light switch and outlet.

Comment: Or, if you're okay with controlling it from an app or alexa/google assistant type thing, you could use smart outlets, such as these: https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/best-smart-switch/

Comment: I'm not crazy about smart outlets, but I'd be willing to try if all else fails.

Comment: I'm OK w/ a junction box and conduit under my desk. I don't know enough about high power electrical work to know where to start, though.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a shopping question, and so would be considered off-topic..

That said, a web search for 'extension cord switch' produced a number of off-the-shelf results that look like they will do exactly what you're looking for. Add one or two regular extension cords if necessary for added length.

[image: one] [image: two] [image: three]

Comment: Chiming in with Greg, it's best to buy the wiring off-the-shelf, as opposed to building it yourself, even if you are somewhat capable but inexperienced. It's a matter of shifting liability in case of damage (e.g. fire) in connection with the wiring.

Comment: I used radio wave activated remote power outlets for such things myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use proper AC mains wiring methods on a desk.  I'm a big fan of metal boxes, EMT conduit and THHN wires within the conduit, since it's so tough you are unlikely to get in too much trouble.  You put either an inlet on the desk, or simply a cord going into a junction box with a proper strain relief, and that cord powers the whole desk.